# A div is not showing

Tags: html, css

I'm not a licensed programmer and I learned to program by myself, that's why my code isn't very clear and I make many mistakes, here is one of them, I hope you can help me with this:
(sry for my English)

```
<div class="cabecera">
    <div class="botondepagina">
        <a href="index.html" style="text-decoration: none;">
            <img src="resources/logo.png" class="logo">
            <h1 class="titulo">DASEMU</h1>
        </a>
    </div>
    <a href="service/mnh/mnh.html" class="MNH">
        <h4>Masternode Hosting</h4>
    </a>
    <a href="service/pool/pool.html" class="pool">
        <h4>Stacking Pool</h4>
    </a>
    <div class="desplegable">
        <h4>Exchange</h4>>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="Dexemu.dasemu.com">Dexsemu</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

ok, the problem is that Dasemu, Masternode Hosting and Exchange are visibles but "desplegable" doesn't appear in the website.
Where is the problem?
[The pic of what is being shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws2Eq.png)

Comment: Your example is missing a closing `div` tag. What is the `css` for `className` `desplegable`? Does it contain anything that hides the `div`?

Comment: Use an editor, it'll probably help you find these errors easier

Comment: Where is the class? Can you please show all the CSS?

Answer (score 2):

you didn't close div tag.

```
<div class="cabecera">
    <div class="botondepagina">
        <a href="index.html" style="text-decoration: none;">
            <img src="resources/logo.png" class="logo">
            <h1 class="titulo">DASEMU</h1>
        </a>
    </div>
    <a href="service/mnh/mnh.html" class="MNH">
        <h4>Masternode Hosting</h4>
    </a>
    <a href="service/pool/pool.html" class="pool">
        <h4>Stacking Pool</h4>
    </a>
    <div class="desplegable">
        <h4>Exchange</h4>>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="Dexemu.dasemu.com">Dexsemu</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- Here -->
```

Comment: Yeah, but in the original code I wrote the 3rd </div>, the problem must be another thing, and as you can see, "master node hosting" and "stacking pool" is being shown...